# Multiple ComboBoxes working together on PowerApps

Tags: combobox, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I wanted to see if anybody on here has encountered this yet...I'm looking to work with multiple ComboBoxes to Filter data in a Gallery. Currently, I have a search bar **(TextInput1.Text)** working in conjunction with multiple ComboBoxes (**ComboBox1** and **ComboBox3**) -- which is attached to the **Gallery > Items Function** :

```
Gallery> Items = Filter('Table A', 
    ((TextInput1.Text in 'Description') || 
     (TextInput1.Text in 'Name - Long') ||
     (TextInput1.Text in 'Tags')) &&
    ('Target Type'.Value exactin ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Result &&
     'Target Level'.Value exactin ComboBox3.SelectedItems.Result)
)
```

***PROBLEM***

The issue with the `('Target Type'.Value exactin ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Result && 'Target Level'.Value exactin ComboBox3.SelectedItems.Result)`, part in the function above is that when you apply the `&&` operator in between **ComboBox1** and **ComboBox2** , none of the data populates on the Gallery unless items are selected on BOTH **ComboBoxes**. Similarly, when using the `||` operator it only responds to the MOST RECENTLY selected items in the boxes.

***POSSIBLE SOLUTION***

In order for multiple ComboBoxes to execute cross-reference functionality(which is essentially what I'm trying to do with multiple boxes), I have to use an **IF** function that follows the following logic:

> IF(more than 1 comboBox is being selected, apply && logic in between ComboBoxes[like shown above], else apply ||)

or

> IF( just 1 combobox is being used, apply || logic, else apply &&)

Am I going about this the right way? If so, how would a function look in its entirety when incorporating this?